# Derivation of mean life of a radioactive nucleus

Tags: nuclear-physics, probability, radioactivity, half-life

How can the mean life of a radioactive nucleus be derived?
Consider R.dt number of nuclei decaying in the time interval t and t+dt. Then, isn't the lifetime of those R.dt number of nuclei is t? But, I couldn't understand why in many derivations, lifetime is mentioned as tR.dt instead of t and we integrate tR.dt from 0 to infinity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Average values are calculated by integrating over a probability distribution:
$$\langle x\rangle=\int_a^b xP(x)\;dx.$$
Thus to solve the problem one must find the probability that a given nuclei does not decay, so that the mean lifetime is given by:
$$\langle t\rangle=\int_0^\infty tP_{not decayed}(t)\; dt.$$
Since we know the probability that a given nucleus will decay is given by the distribution:
$$P_{decayed}(t)=\int_0^t \lambda e^{-\lambda t^\prime}\; dt^\prime=1-e^{-\lambda t},$$ where $\lambda$ is the decay constant of the given radioactive species, and is included for normalization so that:
$$P_{decayed} (t)=\int_0^\infty \lambda{N(t)\over N_0}\; dt=1.$$
So the probability that the given nucleus has not decayed is given by:
$$P_{not decayed}(t)=1-P_{decayed}(t)=e^{-\lambda t}.$$
So that we have the mean life-time as:
$$\langle t\rangle=\int_0^{\infty} te^{-\lambda t}\; dt.$$
Using integration by parts, we find that the mean life time is :
$$\langle t\rangle={1\over \lambda}$$.
Why must we integrate over infinity, because the sample life time is such that $N(t)\rightarrow 0$ asymptoticaly as $t\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

The basic assumption is that the rate of decay is proportional to the number of unstable nuclei,

ie $\dfrac{dN}{dt}\propto N \Rightarrow \dfrac{dN}{dt}= -\lambda N\Rightarrow N = N_0e^{-\lambda t}$

where $\lambda$ is the decay constant and $N_0$ is the number of unstable nuclei at time $t=0$.

As an aside suppose that you started with $15$ and $8$ nuclei decayed in the first two second interval, $4$ nuclei decayed in the second two second interval, $2$ nuclei decayed in the third two second interval and the last nucleus decayed in the fourth two second interval.

How might you **estimate** the mean lifetime of the unstable nuclei?

How about $\langle t\rangle=\dfrac{(8\times 1) + (4 \times 3)+(2\times 5)+(1\times7)}{8+4+2+1} \approx 2.47$.

Where did the $(8\times 1) $ come from?
It comes from the fact that between time $= 0$ and time $= 2$, mid interval time $1$ seconds, eight nuclei decayed and so on for $(\underbrace{4}_{\rm number}\times \underbrace{3}_{\rm mid\,interval})$ etc, with $(8+4+2+1)$ being the total number.

Coming back to the radioactive decay.

The number of unstable nuclei which decay in infinitesimal intervals of time from $t$ to $t+dt$ is

$dN= -\lambda N(t) \,dt=-\lambda N_0e^{-\lambda t} \,dt$.

and the mean lifetime is $\langle t\rangle=\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{t=0}^\infty \left(-\lambda N_0e^{-\lambda t} \,dt\right) \times t}{N_0}=\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$